# Can't Donwload/Install/Update any app - Waiting for download

Tags: applications, google-play-store, troubleshooting, download-manager

I've got a problem while trying to install/upgrade any app on my android phone, after tapping on install/upgrade it just get stuck with the message `waiting for download`.

Nothing works for me, I already tried these solutions and their combinations:

- Restarting the phone
- Clearing google play store cache/data - force stopping it
- Clearing google play service data
- Clearing download manager cache/data - force stopping it
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Play Store updates (also I have tried it without reinstalling)
- Removing & re-adding my Google account from device
- I've got enough free storage [+3G]
- I'm on a WiFi with good connectivity.
- There is no new version of Android available to upgrade for my phone
- I also tried installing apps from browser, didn't work!
- I tried installing apps using a VPN too, Wrap from CloudFlare is the only thing on my phone and it didn't work either.

I'm on Android 8.1
Motorola products, if it makes any difference.

Comment: install apk files

Comment: Thanks but that would be the obvious thing to do... I rather solving the problem.

Comment: assuming you have enough free space for downloading and installing apps, try another wifi maybe it's just a network connection problem not related to your phone. if you're not sure about free space wipe cache from recovery and clear cache for every app from app settings